# SymmetricDS update error duplicate key

Tags: symmetricds

I use SymetricDS and sometimes symmetric raise an error :

```
INFO  [slave] [DefaultDatabaseWriter] [slave-data-loader-1] Failed to process update event in batch 298578.
ERROR [slave] [DataLoaderService]     [slave-data-loader-1] Failed to load batch 000-298578 StackTraceKey [UniqueKeyException:4114584735]
ERROR [master][AcknowledgeService]  [master-push-default-5] The outgoing batch 001-298578 failed: ERREUR: la valeur d'une clé dupliquée rompt la contrainte unique « primary_key_constaint_name » Détail : La clé existe déjà.
```

I have tried to detect and correct conflicts by insert in sym_conflict this row :

```sql
insert into sym_conflict(conflict_id, source_node_group_id, target_node_group_id, detect_type resolve_type, ping_back)
values('master-win', 'master', 'slave', 'USE_CHANGED_DATA', 'INGORE', 'SINGLE_ROW');
```

but this not working. On documentation have found this :

**USE_CHANGED_DATA** : Indicates that the primary key plus any data that has changed on the source system will be used to detect a conflict. If a row exists with the same old values on the target system as they were on the source system for the columns that have changed on the source system, then **no conflict is detected during an update or a delete**. If a row already exists during an insert then a conflict has been detected.

How symmetric can detect PK conflicts on a update and ignore it ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No conflict detection, neither resolution is required in such cases. By default symmetricDs on insert if there's already a row with the same primary key on the target node will fall back to update and vice versa for an update falling back to an insert: http://www.symmetricds.org/doc/3.6/user-guide/html-single/user-guide.html#d4e104

Comment: Thanks, but this not working in my symmetric (3.8), symmetric retry and fails every time

Comment: have you removed the data from sym_conflict?

Comment: yes I have removed data in `sym_conflict`, `sym_conflit` is empty. The outgoing batch always fails.

Comment: what's the value of the column `DATA_LOADER_TYPE` in the table `sym_channel`?

Comment: the value is `default`

Comment: Then I would recommend checking out the source code of the deployed version, configuring the server to listen to a debug port, add some breakpoints in the code and debug. That's how I learned a lot